# CEF sharp browser wait till website fully loaded

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using CEFsharp browser and determine the page finish loading with LoadingStateChanged event but it fires many times.

I need it to fire only once the page has fully loaded, how can this be done?

```
private async void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Browser.IsLoading)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        });

        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Page has been loaded");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the correct event. Have you tried different URLs? What version are you using? You'll need to provide more information. Also remember that CefSharp is just a wrapper

Answer (score 4):

These days its really simple. Put for example these 2 lines of Code in ur Form_Load:

```
  browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
  (browser).FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;
```

Then add the required methode:

```
async void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{ // Jumps in here when the page is fully loaded:
    if (e.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        if (e.Url.Contains("whatever you need"))
        {
            // Call a methode or something else.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, I use (a variation of) the following workaround.
I keep track of the number of requests made and only do an action if there is a newer request.
For my case, this seems to work fine. However I can imagine that the browser actually still does something and you would sometimes need to wait for the last time it finishes.

```
using CefSharp;

public class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler
{
    //left all the irrelevant IRequestHandler methods out of this example code, but you'll need to implement them
    public int NrOfCalls { get; set; }
    public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
    {
        NrOfCalls++;
        return false;
    }
}
public class Handle
{
    private RequestHandler _requestHandler;
    private IWebBrowser _browser;
    private int previousRequestNrWhereLoadingFinished = -1;

    public Handle()
    {
        _requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
        _browser.RequestHandler = _requestHandler;
    }
    private void _browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if page has finished loading
        if (!e.IsLoading)
        {
            //sometimes this is called multiple times for one request, we will only do something if it comes from a newer request than the previous action
            if (previousRequestNrWhereLoadingFinished < _requestHandler.NrOfCalls)
            {
                previousRequestNrWhereLoadingFinished = _requestHandler.NrOfCalls;
                ThisMethodWillOnlyBeCalledOncePerRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```